# What is preventing my code from getting the JSON?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to attach ajax data to my $scope object with Angular JS using the Angular JS http service so I can add a success handler to update my $scope and view when the data arrives. In a previous post, the solution I was given for this was a modification of my original code. This is the solution I was given was:

```
function getStuff(num) {
$http.jsonp('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.mysite.com/api' + num) + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
    .success(function (contents) {
        alert(contents); //I just want to check and see if the contents arrived
        $scope.shows = contents;
    });
};
getStuff(6387);
```

For some reason, it's not doing anything and I've injected it into my controller too. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what happens? Does the browser fetch the data? Are the contents returned (do you get an alert)?

Comment: Not sure if this is going to help, maybe post your controller as well, so we can take a look at how you're calling `getStuff`. Also, can you add an `.error` callback to your http so you can check that an error isn't being returned?

Comment: Can you show the code from the controller or service this lies in?

Comment: use the developer tools in chrome (press F12) or the Firebug plugin to firefox. Check for errors in the Java Console and watch the network traffic.
Is there any call done at all? Do you have JS errors?

You can provide your example plication as a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/ this way Stackoverflow users can quickly help you identify your problem.
as you do basic stuff that usually works fine, it will be quick to help you if you provide enough information to reproduce the problem.